# How to make a key write a specific command everytime i use it in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to set a specific key to write a custom command every time I type it inside the terminal window. Can this be done?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the type of command that you would like to run when pressing a key (or key combination)? This will make it easier to know what sort of command needs to be constructed (straight command, script, etc.). Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with "tap it"? Have you searched for similar questions in AskUbuntu?

Comment: Hii the command is sudo -s typical right & i'm using the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 !

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by editing `$HOME/.inputrc` (create the file if it doesn't exist already). For example, to have the key <kbd>f</kbd> enter the command `ls`, you would add this line to `$HOME/.inputrc`:

```
f: "ls"
```

Now, every time you press <kbd>f</kbd>, the word `ls` will appear in the terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute it. For something a bit more useful that won't render a key useless, you can use a key combination. For example, to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> insert `ls`, add this line instead:

```
Control-f: "ls"
```

And to have it executed directly, add a newline to the end:

```
Control-f: "ls\n"
```

Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>  will execute the `ls` command.

Note that all of these changes will only take effect when you launch a new shell (open a new terminal).